# Databricks Create a list of dataFrames with their size

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm working on Databricks and I want to have a list of all my dataframes with their number of observations.

Is it possible to have the size (number of rows) for each dataframe in the DataLake?

I found how to list all dataframmes:

```
display(dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/mnt/adls/fraud/qal/landing"))*
```

I know how to count it.

Is it possible to have a list of my dataframes and the size?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `DataFrame` from the file listing and the row counts. The following code assumes all your tables are in Parquet format. If that's not the case, you need to change the reading code.

```
def namesAndRowCounts(root: String) =
  spark.createDataFrame(
    dbutils.fs.ls(root).map { info =>
      (info.name, spark.read.load(info.path).count)
    }
  ).toDF("name", "rows").orderBy('name)

display(namesAndRowCounts("/mnt/adls/fraud/qal/landing"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have avro format so the reading code will be different

Comment: Avro was not mentioned in the question but it doesn't change the approach: you just have to add `.format("com.databricks.spark.avro")` before `load()`. For more details, see: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-avro.html

Comment: Any chance you could convert this to Python? I've tried but I get an error with the SparkContext on Workers:

Comment: from pyspark.sql import Row

def namesAndRowCounts(root):
  row = sc.parallelize(dbutils.fs.ls(root)).map(lambda info: Row(name=info.name, path=info.path, rows=sqlContext.load(info.path).count()))
  #It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
  return sqlContext.createDataFrame(row)